# how to support different resolutions in 4.0.3?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am prepared one application in 4.0.3. My application support to all resolutions for that i have prepared different layout like,

```
  layout-hdpi
  layout-land-hdpi
  layout-large-port
  layout-large-land
  layout-xlarge-port
  layout-xlarge-land
```

when i have run my application in 1024x600 with 240 density it is taking layout-hdpi file and when i run the application in 1280x800 with 160 density it is taking layout-large file.Please tell me how to over come this problem. please help.

Comment: what is your problem?the large and x-large attribute are not related to the resolution but to the physical size of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [modifiers for tablets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). This allows usage of folders like "layout-sw600dp" or "layout-w1024dp". Create folders with this format and place your resources in the corresponding folder.

Comment: thanks for reply . Just i have changed layout names layout-large to layout-w600dp.But it is taking layout from default layout folder

Comment: Propably because you have specified the width to exactly 600 dp. You should define the folder with "sw600dp" which means "smallest width 600 dp".

Comment: Your comment is not a valid sentence. Please explain what the matter with these values is.

Comment: just i have changed layout name layout-w600dp to layout-sw600dp.Now also it is working

Answer (score 0):

With your specifiers, you can filter a device either by their density (ie: pixels per inch) using ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, or by the actual screen size (small, large, xlarge), as specified [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range). As stated recently, you can also provide a resource by the minimum resolution (aka smallest width : sw600dp) qualifier.

As per [the documentation], if you give multiple qualifier, you must give them in a specific order.

Finally, when you ask for a resource, Android tries to find the [best match](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), first by eliminating the resources which don't apply to the current device, evaluating one qualifier after the other in the order defined earlier.